# Getting the highest number from a mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

My issue is I need to create an order so I can move items up and down in this web application. However, I can not index the order(ord column) values by an index with an incremental value because there are several companies in the same table that use this column.

My table structure is this:
[image]

Right now I am thinking that the easiest way would be to do a MAX and grab the highest number and use that as an index in a way so you never end up with the same number twice for a specific companies listing when you go to add a new entry for a company.

```
SELECT MAX(ord) FROM phonebook WHERE `id_company` = "51";
```

Would this be a wise route to go? OR maybe create a new database for each client and create and index and use that as a way order entries?

Comment: I'm confused.  What is order based on? What are your expected results using the sample data you have?

Comment: No, 2 transactions running at the same time can get you the same MAX value, resulting in 2 times the same order. YOu would have to lock (large) parts of the table at least to make it work consistent.

Comment: Also, it looks like you have some normalization issues. If a user-company relationship is one-to-one, you shouldn't store that relationship in this table.

Comment: Doing this really defeats the purpose of an index because `ord` already has duplicates - it's nice that going forward `ord` would be clean, but you'd just be polishing a turd - it's still gross. I think your best bet is to create a new column. Don't forget about going forward - an "index" that is only an index under certain circumstances is a poor foundation that will likely cause more issues than in solves in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you aim for less than complete perfection in your assignment of `ord` values. You can get away with this as follows:

1. don't make `ord` unique. (It isn't).
2. rely on the ordering of `phonebook_name` to get a good order of names. MySQL has these wonderful case-insensitive collations for precisely this purpose.
3. I suppose you're trying to make some of the entries for a company come first, and others come last. Set the `ord` column to `50` for everybody, then give the entries you want first lower numbers, and the ones you want last higher numbers.

When you display data for a particular company, do it like this ...

```
SELECT whatever, whatever
  FROM phonebook
 WHERE id_company = 11
 ORDER BY ord, phonebook_name, phonebook_number, id_phonebook
```

This `ORDER BY` clause will do what you want, and it will be stable if there are duplicates.  You can then, in your user interface, move an entry up with a query like this.

```
UPDATE phonebook SET ord=ord-1 WHERE id_phonebook = :recordnumber
```